# Prevent Redux-Thunk from re-requesting data that already is in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use redux thunk to make asynchronous actions and it is updating my store the way I want it to. I have data for my charts within `this.props` by using:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const key = state.key ? state.key : {}
  const data = state.data[key] ? state.data[key] : {}
  return {
    data,
    key
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LineChart)
```

Where data is an object within the store and each time I make an XHR call to get another piece of data it goes into the store.

This is the the async and the sync action

```
export function addData (key, data, payload) {
  return {
    type: ADD_DATA,
    key,
    data,
    payload
  }
}

export function getData (key, payload) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    services.getData(payload)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(addData(key, response.data, payload))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('axios error', error)
      })
  }
}
```

And the reducer:

```
const addData = (state, action) => {
  const key = action.key
  const data = action.data.results
  const payload = action.payload
  return {
    ...state,
    payload,
    key,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [key]: data
    }
  }
}
```

In [the tutorial](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/complete-intro-react/) I have been following along with ([code on github](https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react/blob/v2-24/js/Details.js)), this seems like enough that when a piece of data that already exists within the store, at say like, `data['some-key']` redux will not request the data again. I'm not entirely sure on how it's prevented but in the course, it is. I however am definitely making network calls again for keys that already exist in my store

## What is the way to prevent XHR for data that already exists in my store?

Comment: I would check for data existence on my action (by calling `getState` and checking if it's there; If it is, dispatch it otherwise do you service call.

Answer (score -1):

Redux itself does nothing about requesting data, or only requesting it if it's not cached.  However, *you* can write logic for that.  Here's a fake-ish example of what a typical "only request data if not cached" thunk might look like:

```
function fetchDataIfNeeded(someId) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        const items = selectItems(state);

        if(!dataExists(items, someId)) {
            fetchData(someId)
                .then(response => {
                    dispatch(loadData(response.data));
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I also have [a gist with examples of common thunk patterns](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea4d0a6ce56ee479fe8b356e099f857e) that you might find useful.

Comment: Yes I thought of doing something like this and then I guess I'd call the sync action, however I was more interested if I had missed some pattern from the tutorial where they seem to have avoided this clunky bit of logic